# Pass safetynet check in Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I wonder if it is possible to make an Android emulator pass safetynet.
I made an emulator with google play services installed. I installed magisk and installed the universal safetynet fix but still basic integrity and CTS profile fails.

When I google search this question there aren't a lot of  results on this topic but the one I found suggested that it is not possible..